# .htaccess change / in match to &

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to have te following URLs on my page:

```
www.domain.com/<module>/<function>/<query>=<string>/<query>=<string>/<query>=<string>
```

I know how to match the part with the module and function to valid urls like this:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?module=<module>&function=<function>
```

But I have no idea how I can append all those query=string-parameters to the query string.

I currently use `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?module=$1&function=$2 [NC]`as my rule and would like to add those (optional and repeatable) query-string parts.

I hope someone knows more about htaccess and regexp than me xD

Comment: Don't think you can do that generally (you could do it for a limited number of pairs tho). You could just pass the whole `<query>=<string>/<query>=<string>/<query>=<string>` part to your script as is, and let it handle the parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules need to be placed in **.htaccess** file in website root folder.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([a-z0-9_]+)=([^/]+)/?$ $1/?$2=$3 [NC,N,DPI,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/?$ /index.php?module=$1&function=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

1. They will rewrite URL (internally) from this form

   `http://www.example.com/main/job/p1=value/p2=something+else/PP=yes`

   into this form

   `http://www.example.com/index.php?module=main&function=job&p1=value&p2=something+else&PP=yes`
2. These rules need to be placed somewhere on the top of .htaccess -- first rule uses `[N]` flag which tells Apache to start rewriting from start again (in order to rewrite all `<query>=<string>` fragments). If you have a lot of rules before this one, Apache will have to "probe" each rule after each iteration, which may put unnecessary load on web server.